List google drive folder contents where folder is name is based on cell value [solved]
I'm using the original code borrowed from this post to list the contents of a specified folder from drive.
List Google drive folder contents to google sheets with only new files
function wthFolderContents() {
  var folder_id = 'myFolderID';
   
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id)
  var contents = folders.getFiles();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  sheet.clearContents()
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );
  
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow ( [name, link] );

What I need is this variable here to be based on the cell value in A1:
 var folder_id = 'myFolderID';

I either need to retrieve the folder ID in another cell based on the value of cell A1 and have the script reference that cell, or have the code dynamically lookup the folder ID based on cell A1.
Any help greatly appreciated.

this variable here to be based on the cell value in A1 You need to use getValue(). Since this is one of the most basic processes of apps script, I strongly suggest that you refer to the documentation and learn how this is done.

I have read and revisited this entire post, including comments. It seems that the result of the comments have fallen far from the original post. Please edit your question to include your requirements and limitations. Please clarify this and thats of your project to make it more understandable for the community and also the future readers. Comment, can be deleted and is not going to be permanent. I understand that you are looking to refer to some sort of an identifier on your data please clarify that and make it a specific question. Edit the question accordingly.

Here is the solution to my specific problem. When the script is run, it displays every file in the folder 'id here'. I then just run a simple query on colA (JOB#) to filter just the file names I require.
function getAndListFilesInFolder() {
  var arr,f,file,folderName,subFolders,id,mainFolder,name,own,sh,thisSubFolder,url;

  sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('google_drive');
  sh.getRange(1, 1, 100, 10).clear({contentsOnly: true})

  id = "id here";
  arr = [["JOB#","DOCUMENT NAME", "URLs", "OWNER"]];

  mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  subFolders = mainFolder.getFolders();
  folderName = mainFolder.getName();

  f = mainFolder.getFiles();

  while (f.hasNext()) {
    file = f.next();
    name = file.getName()
    url = file.getUrl()
    own = file.getOwner().getName()

    arr.push([folderName, name, url, own]);
  };

  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    thisSubFolder = subFolders.next();
    f = thisSubFolder.getFiles();
    folderName = thisSubFolder.getName();

    while (f.hasNext()) {
      file = f.next();
      name = file.getName()
      url = file.getUrl()
      own = file.getOwner().getName()

      arr.push([folderName,name, url, own]);  
    };
  };

  sh.getRange(1,1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
  sh.getRange(2,1, arr.length, arr[0].length).sort(1);
}


You can try this:
From:
var folder_id = 'myFolderID';

To:
var folder_id = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue(); 

Please follow the arrangement of this complete modified code:
function wthFolderContents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  var folder_id = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue(); 
   
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id)
  var contents = folders.getFiles();
  
  sheet.clearContents()
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );
  
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow ( [name, link] );

  }

}

Sample Output:

Reference:
getValue()

UPDATE:

Here's the sample value of cell A1 before you run the script. It should contain a valid Folder Id.

Here's how you can get the Folder Id.
From your desired folder, copy the highlighted part of the URL then paste it in the cell A1 of your spreadsheet, see the below image for your reference:


Thanks EL SRY. The variable 'row' doesn't have an action associated with it? I forgot to mention that there is a parent folder involved. I've tried defining the parentFolderID with the URL, but how do I link this variable to either 'folders' or 'contents'?

Thanks for your reply. Could you please clarify the context of this line I've tried defining the parentFolderID with the URL, but how do I link this variable to either 'folders' or 'contents'? this way, we can understand your question better and help you solve it.

There is a parentFolder involved on google drive, so the variable 'folders' needs to reference the parentFolder URL. I've defined the variable to hold the URL, but I don't know how to write it in the code.

Thanks for the additional information. If I understand your question correctly, you want the folder Id to be declared in a variable instead of referencing the value of A1, Could you please confirm? if I misunderstood your follow-up question I apologize, please provide more clarification if this is incorrect.

The code above is retrieving documents from google drive based on value in cell A1. However, it is trying to retrieve the files from the root folder on drive, because the parent folder has not yet been defined. When I run the code above, I get the following exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.
wthFolderContents @ Code.gs:6 - I am assuming this is because the parent folder is not defined or referenced.

Thank you for clarifying your question. You received the error because your cell A1 in your spreadsheet with the sheet named SheetName does not contain the valid folder Id. Please include your folderId in the cell A1 as the code gets the value of cell A1 and use it as reference to get the name and URL of your files from your folder.

I have updated my answer for your reference on how you can get the folder Id and how the cell A1 should look like. Please see the UPDATE portion of my answer, feel free to try it on your end, and do not hesitate to add your thoughts on how it turns out.

Thank-you for your updated answer. However, this is not what I am requiring. The user is not going to know the URL each time. All the user knows is the value in A1, which is a 5 digit number. They type that number in cell A1, run the script, and it displays the files. So, as per my original post questioning whether I need a script that lookups the folder URL based on the value of A1 and how to reference that in the script. For example then, cell A2 contains 5 digit number. Cell A1 lookups value in A2 and dynamically provides the URL. Then your code should work (in theory).

Thanks for providing details, Could you please share with me how you are storing the file path and the reference you are referring to? It looks like it is now some sort of a searching a database type of question, using a reference number to search a path, with a pre-existing relationship with each other, do you mind sharing that relationship if there is?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
